# How do I stop Mail.app from opening previous emails on launch?

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard, apple-mail

Every time I launch Mail.app it opens up a new window for each of the email messages I was checking previously. How do I stop this from happening? It only opens the emails that I launched in a new window previously, not every email message I hover over.

Comment: Close the mail viewer windows before quitting Mail.app. Seriously, it's a useful, state-preserving feature. Press `Cmd-Opt-W` or `Opt-click` the close button of one of Mail's windows to close them all, just before you quit.

Comment: Should have made that the answer Daniel. Thanks!

Comment: I have a better question: how to prevent it from NOT not reopening all my windows!? I rely on the functionality, and, once in a while, everything is closed. Thanks, Apple! I love relying on features that only work 98% of the time. So wonderful to randomly have to dig through my email again when I already, specially, opened all the mails that required my action in anticipation.

Answer (score 1):

if you really want to be lazy you could  put this script in your script menu and run it when you open mail

```
tell application "Mail"
    set window_names to name of every window
    repeat with awindow in window_names
        if awindow does not contain "messages" then close (first window whose name is awindow)
    end repeat
end tell
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's one (rather hacky, but working) way:

1. Arrange the Mail App exactly how you want it to open.
2. Quit it.
3. Open the Terminal (Applications > Utilities > Terminal).
4. Paste the following line and hit enter:

   ```
   chmod -w ~/Library/Saved\ Application\ State/com.apple.mail.savedState
   ```

If you ever want to undo it, repeat steps 3 and 4, but with `+w` instead of `-w`.

Tested on OS X 10.10.5.